Deleting/Replacing Cythonized Modules
I want to delete and/or replace cythonized module created with cython (command line utility) but I couldn't find any information on how to do it. How do I delete/replace it? Thanks.
OS: Windows 11
Python Version: 3.12
Cython Version: 3.0.11
Tried manually going to the path (Path to python folder)\Lib\site-packages, but could not find any module named what I named it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
